# fileinput: not able to print list after for loop ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm trying to create a 2D array for a matrix I will input, where each line will
be added as an array inside of *array_1,* the 2D array. During the for loop, it will print if I type print, but for the final line, *"print(array_1)"*, nothing is printed nor is any error message given. What is causing this? I want to be able to use array_1 and print it. Thanks.

```
import fileinput
#creates empty array:
array_1 = []
for line in fileinput.input():
#appends the original array:
        new_array = [str(line)]
        array_1.append(new_array)
fileinput.close()
#doesn't print anything here:
print(array_1)
```

Comment: Are you providing any input in standard input stream? Or providing files when running the command?

Comment: can you print the ´str(line)´ in the for loop? Btw you need to transform your input line into floats if you want to be able to do calculations with your matrix.

Comment: @VikrantSharma I'm simply pasting the input into the program when i run it

Comment: @Sharku i can print lines while the loop is running but not outside of the loop

Comment: Just try `python your_script_name.py your_script_name.py`. This should output lines of your script and verify that some output is coming.

Comment: @VikrantSharma unfortunately this didnt work either

Comment: The code you've posted, is that the complete script? Because I checked for that and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
import fileinput
#creates empty array:
array_1 = []
for line in fileinput.input("/home/anil/Downloads/zip_folder_structure"):
    #appends the original array:
    print(line)
    new_array = [str(line)]
    array_1.append(new_array)
fileinput.close()
#doesn't print anything here:
print(array_1)
```

print line

```
['_cluster_frame']
['ca1670d2-f361-450e-be3b-7359711d2199_1']
['image_1.000000_.jpg']
```

print array_1

```
[['_cluster_frame']
['ca1670d2-f361-450e-be3b-7359711d2199_1']
['image_1.000000_.jpg']]
```

Try to check what you are getting in **line** in your **for loop** statement. Possibly you are getting file with no data.

Comment: pass file name in fileinput.input("file_name") statement, and it will work

Comment: This fixed it @AnilKumarGupta . Any idea why my method only printed lines inside of the for loop but not out? Thanks

Comment: @AlexBoyle Your code snippet is correct, As I suggested you can validate line by line data passing file_path similarly you can validate through user input as suggested by Vikarant. Put your code into a module called, matrix.py , run module through command line using  python path_to/matrix.py . It will wait for user input pass some value example "Line1" press ENTER and pass next value "LINE2" so on .. Finally press CTRL + D . You will able to see after every ENTER your passed value ['"Line1"] ['"Line2"'] and finally matrix data [['"LINE1"],['"LINE2"] ]

Comment: @AlexBoyle has it fixed now ??